# Difference between unrestricted and internal vertical mode

Tags: tex-core

At any point in the processing of a document, TeX can be in one of seven modes: no mode (only in `\write` and similar commands, I think), math mode (`$...$`), display math mode (`$$...$$`), restricted horizontal mode (`\hbox{...}`), unrestricted horizontal (paragraphs), internal vertical mode (`\vbox{...}`) or on the main vertical list.

What are the differences between the two vertical modes?

Obviously, there can be no page breaks within a `\vbox`, so I'll refine my question into: assuming that TeX is currently on the main vertical list, what are the differences between doing

```
\setbox0\vbox{... material ...}\unvbox0
```

and putting `... material ...` directly in the main vertical list?

Comment: Please feel free to correct my use of the various terms: I don't have the TeXbook at hand to check them.

Comment: I don't have my copy of TB either, but what about glue?  Isn't it set when `\unvbox`ing?  (I'm not sure, can't remember that.)

Comment: @mbork: `\setbox0\vbox{!\vfill!}\unvbox0\bye` puts a `!` at the top of the page, and another one midway (one `\vfill` between the two `!`, one for the end of the page). So no, the glue is not set. Another way to see that is to add `\showbox0` before unboxing: I see the item `.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as the typesetting is concerned there is no difference whatsoever to my knowledge (in contrast to the situation when you do

```
\setbox0\hbox{... material ...}\unhbox0
```

which handles language nodes somewhat differently if I recall correctly (without a TB)).
But there is of course one difference in that any local assignment within  "material" will be reverted if it happens inside a box but obviously not if entered in directly.

As pointed out one other difference is that on the main vertical list, removals such as `\unkern`, `\unskip`, `\lastbox` and`` `\unpenalty `` are not allowed, while they can be used within the `\vbox`. So for manipulation while preparing the material the vbox can have some advantage.

Comment: `\insert` comes to mind as something that fails in inner vmode, doesn't it?

Comment: @Bruno `\insert` should work, they stay in the vbox but migrate to the vertical list when `\unvbox` happens. However, you are right there might be a difference here, because TeX exercises the pagebuilder directly after the insert and that has no effect in vmode. That might need some checking/looking at the code. I doubt that the TB will be precise enough in such a detail.

Comment: Ah, your reply raises one point, then: the page builder is of course only exercised after the whole `\vbox` is processed. I guess my confusion about `\insert` is that LaTeX figures refuse to be used in inner vmode. Why is that? (Perhaps worth a separate question?)

Comment: @Bruno that's because they would not work if they where kept inside the box (but you unbox that level and then it is ok).

Answer (score 4):

(References are to the TeXbook)

The operation `\lastbox` is not allowed in unrestricted vertical mode (p. 222).

`\end` and `\dump` are not allowed in internal vertical mode.

Note also that marks issued in internal vertical mode don't migrate (p. 259), so they won't be seen unless the constructed `\vbox` or `\vtop` is unboxed.

Comment: Marks seem to migrate when you `\unvbox`: `\setbox0\vbox{\mark{abc}}\unvbox0 X\par\vfill\break\show\botmark\bye` shows `\botmark:abc`. Alternatively, just do `\tracingall\showlists` after `\unvbox0`. On the other hand, your point about `\lastbox`, `\end` and `\dump` is very right.

Comment: @egreg the second sentence is a red herring I would say. In the question as framed there is nothing to migrate as the box is unboxed. This statement refers to a mark or insert being kept inside a box when the page is being build together.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch No, they don't migrate: if you unbox, they aren't inside a box any more. I'd compare this with the similar situation with restricted horizontal mode, where marks *do* migrate to the enclosing vertical mode.

Comment: @egreg: the whole point of my question is that I'm `\unvbox`-ing the box after constructing it, so in my context, `\marks` do migrate. I think your answer has useful material for people browsing this, but is a little bit off the initial question, so I accepted Frank's as "more helpful". Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I intend "migrate" in the sense that the object is taken out from the box in which it is, while the box remains unaltered under every other respect. This isn't the case when you `\unvbox`.